# How to calculate collective noise from individual standard errors?

Tags: variance, standard-deviation, standard-error

I have a data which is a series of standard errors(SE) of n elements. I need to get the a measure of collective noise in the data which takes in account of individual standard errors(SE) of all the elements.
The way I feel I can do that is as following.

I can get variance (VAR) of each element by multiplying SE by square root of n and then squaring it.

$Var_{i}=(SE_{i}*\sqrt n)^2$

So then I can divide the sum of variances by square of n - which would give me variance in the condition.

$Var=\frac {(Var_{1}+Var_{2}+Var_{3}+..)}{n^2}$

Code sample (python 2.7):

```
import numpy as np
SE=np.array([0.925239,0.432151,0.423826,0.417018,0.418650])

n=len(SE)
Varis=[np.power((SEi*np.sqrt(n)),2) for SEi in SE]
Var=sum(Varis)/np.power(n,2)
print Var
```

`0.3143244014044001`

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Please tell us what you mean by "cumulative variance": your formula, by ignoring variation in the means of those "elements," does not appear to provide their actual cumulative variance.  And could you also stipulate what you mean by "best way"?  Would that mean simplest, fastest, clearest, most reliable, or something else?

Comment: +1 I voted to reopen this question (after the edit) because it can now be understood as a request to estimate *components of variance*. Specifically, given an iid sample $(X_i)$ from a distribution $F$ and measurements of that sample, $Y_i=X_i+\varepsilon_i$, having independent, zero-mean errors $\varepsilon_i$ of given variances $\sigma_i$, how to estimate the variance of $F$?  If this is not the intended interpretation, please let us know by further clarifying your question.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I meant: 
`estimating variance of` $F$ `given variances` $\sigma_{i}$. 
Please feel free to edit my question. I guess I made it kind of confusing.